# Add 1 hour to a column in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an MS Excel table with Date in column A and time in Column B, C, D, E, F.

After loading the table in a data frame, I want to subtract 1 hour from column B, C, D, E, F.

Here is the code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename)

df.columns=['Date','ColB','ColC','ColD','ColE', 'ColF']

df['Delta'] = df['ColB'].apply(lambda x: timedelta(hours=1))#Add column for 1 hour

df['ColB_New']=df['ColB'] + df['Delta']
```

The error I get is:

> 'TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('

Please suggest a solution.

Here is the sample data:

[image]

Comment: please provide some input data

Answer (score 1):

That error is letting you know that one or more of your columns contains non-datetime rows. Check the columns with something like `df.dtypes`. I often find when reading from excel that I have to convert my columns with `pd.to_datetime`, say `df['ColB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ColB'])`.

Comment: The Date column has type datetime64[ns]. All other columns are type 'object'. After converting my ColB to datetime, I get this error : TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime